# Problem with ImageMosaic plugin of Geoserver - invalid shapefile/tif missing in GetCapabilities

Tags: geoserver, wms, image-mosaic

I'm trying to use the ImageMosaic plugin of Geoserver for raster time-series data (I followed this tutorial: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) but it's not working. 
I have a folder with several images (yyyymmddThhmm.tif) and the 3 files:

-timeregex.properties:
`regex=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{4}`

-indexer.properties:
`TimeAttribute=time
Schema= the_geom:Polygon,location:String,time:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](time)`

-store.properties:
`Levels=0.010258701020382227,0.010258701020382227
Heterogeneous=false
TimeAttribute=time
AbsolutePath=false
Name=radar
TypeName=radar
Caching=false
ExpandToRGB=false
LocationAttribute=location
LevelsNum=1`

but in the WMS GetCapabilities, there is only one date displayed in "Dimension" as you can see (and the hour is wrong, it always writes 00:00:00):

[image]

Moreover, something's also wrong with the shapefile created when I created my store cause I cannot open it with any software (QGIS for example tells me it's an invalid data source).

Does anyone have any idea as to what could be my problem? What I did wrong or forget?

Comment: I do not have an answer yet, but I think it is poorly documented.  It isn't at all obvious how to mod things.  The source code at https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/properties/time/TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI.java and https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/aa0d0346e4bb4a5a2055559c22d2b12ded7cbd20/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/properties/time/TimestampFileNameExtractor.java hint that you could also set a timeregex.properties:format SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Also https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/aa0d0346e4bb4a5a2055559c22d2b12ded7cbd20/modules/plugin/imagemosaic/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/imagemosaic/properties/time/TimeParser.java details all the time formats it tries.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the source but I recall reading that if a shapefile is used to store the mosaic indices (i.e. if a datastore.properties file specifying a valid database is not present upon mosaic creation) then the time resolution is limited to days and so hours, minutes etc. will be lost using this method.

Not sure regarding the invalid shapefile, what I did to get around the limited time resolution issue was to set up an empty PostgreSQL database and create a datastore.properties file pointing to it (see https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html).